# How to handle bit to boolean functionality in Postgresql

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, database-migration

As a part of database migration from MSSQL to PostgreSQL, found problem in converting bit to boolean in POSTGRESQL.

**In MSSQL**:      **bit datatype**  can take **1,0,true,false** as values for input parameters .

**IN PostgreSQL**: bit datatype can only take **only  1 and 0** as values.

**So how to pass 'true'/'false' value for bit columns in PostgreSQL**.
The **Application code** is **.NET** . Can this be achieved in **Application level** if not database level?
Can this be handled using ngpsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this at the application level.

A database-level fix would be to change the PostgreSQL column type to `boolean` so that it accepts only `true`/`false` values, but I bet there are a number of uses in your system that expect the numeric equivalent `0`/`1` values.  This will also affect how the values display in reports or if pasted into Excel, for example.

I would decide based on which internal representation leads to the least maintenance work in system conversion.